# How to disable the BlockedThreadChecker of Vert.x?

Tags: vert.x

The BlockedThreadChecker causes a lot of stdout when debugging vert.x code.
This question relates to vert.x 3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
options.setBlockedThreadCheckInterval(1000*60*60);
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vertx/BlockedThreadChecker/vertx/MWx8ma7Ig4o/rFqdYdDErtYJ

NOTE: Disable only for debugging. Otherwise issues which can affect the performance of Vert.x can't be located easily.

Comment: Please really only do this when debugging, never in production. If you have code that blocks the event loop, fix that code, e.g. by moving parts of it to a worker.

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively you can add the following system property to the vertx startup script, will set the event loop execute time to 10 seconds (note the input is in NS):

-Dvertx.options.maxEventLoopExecuteTime=10000000000

Comment: Does this still work in the latest version 4+ in 2023?  It does not work for me.

Answer (score 9):

For anybody interested on this, in case you don't want to change vertx options, you can set the log level to `ERROR` or `OFF` for `BlockedThreadChecker`.

Configuration in logback.xml will look something like this:

```
<configuration>
    ...
        <logger name="io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker" level="OFF" />
    ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Our thread blocking issues are during deployment so we simply turn off logging dynamically during deployment and turn it back on once that's complete
log4j2 this looks like:

```
        org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger threadStuckLogger = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger)LogManager.getLogger(BlockedThreadChecker.class);
        Level threadStuckLevel = threadStuckLogger.getLevel();
        threadStuckLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);

// deploy....

        threadStuckLogger.setLevel(threadStuckLevel);
```